# contents of cookie generated by passport js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, nodes, passport-local

I am triyng to build a node application

I am using passport js local-strategy to authenticate users. I have 3 questions

1.) when users login a cookie is created by the passport . can anybody tell me what is stored in the cookie ?

2.) Is there a way to see the contents of the cookie set by passport?

3.) I have observed that the cookie generated by passport does not get deleted when user logout i.e when req.logout() is called, so do we have to delete it or is it okay if it stays? what will be the contents of the cookie after user is logged out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Passport js does not create a cookie. Passport js is an authentication tool that (only the Local case story is here I m talking about of course) get user's name/password, compares the username that user sent, and the username in the database. Also, it takes the hash of the password and compares the hashed version of the password in database (Since password saved database as hashed / no one wants to keep the plain-text password in the database). If its true it confirms authentication. Also for register (to save user and hashed password), you have to use password js.

But all this scenario is useless if we don't have to keep the user logged in. At this point, you have to use cookies/sessions/jwt tokens to keep info that shows the user is legit. To create a session/cookie  you have to use another library. I think the most common one is express-session. Express session doesn't keep all user info on the cookie. It creates a cookie and holds a key that is related to your data. Hence your data is held on the server-side only and is safe.

**Edit:** I realized my last paragraph before edit has some wrong/missing information. So I deleted the last paragraph and the corrected version is below:

What you store inside the session cookie is specified by serializing/ deserializing functions. These functions are provided by passport js since its the authentication library. A typical serializing/deserializing is like this

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user); 
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null,user)
});
```

Here, "done" is the callback function and the user is the info you re putting in your cookie. It doesn't have to be user, you can only save the userId or something else.

serializeUser function is called after login and just before your session is created. deserializeUser function is called with every request that has a cookie. What it does is basically to get user information from cookie and put it in the req.session.passport.

Lastly, let's look at what session cookies look alike. Here is an example session cookie that is saved on the server-side.

```
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":2591971094,"expires":"2020-09-24T21:11:05.721Z","httpOnly":false,"path":"/"},"passport":{"user":{"_id":"5f307fc99f5c667918a56122","username":"test","__v":0}},"__lastAccess":1598389894627}
```